# creating charts with vba script

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a script to create charts, one per line in my table. The idea is to get a line graph to show the history.

the table looks like this:

```
date  modem  capacity  used 
16/01/2017  PUT       20gb  54%  20/01/2017  73%  21/01/2017  80%  
16/01/2017  PATITIFA  20gb  73%  20/01/2017  79%  21/01/2017 90%  
16/01/2017  HAWAIKI   40gb  44%  20/01/2017  55%  21/01/2017  70%  
16/01/2017  NUI       60gb  48%  20/01/2017  61%  21/01/2017  80%  
16/01/2017  ITI       20gb  75%  20/01/2017  84%  21/01/2017  90%  
16/01/2017  huawei    20gb  37%  20/01/2017  45%  21/01/2017  60%
```

my vba script that is trying to create the tables is here:

```
Sub addchart()
Dim chartPut, chartPatitifa, chartHawaiki, chartNui, chartIti, chartHuawei As Chart
Dim iRow, iCol As Long
Dim date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, date6 As String
Dim conso1, conso2, conso3, conso4, conso5, conso6 As String
Dim forfait As String
Dim modem As String


iRow = 2
iCol = 1


Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 1))
    date1 = Cells(iRow, 1).Value
    modem = Cells(iRow, 2).Value
    forfait = Cells(iRow, 3).Value
    conso1 = Cells(iRow, 4).Value
    date2 = Cells(iRow, 5).Value
    conso2 = Cells(iRow, 6).Value
    date3 = Cells(iRow, 7).Value
    conso3 = Cells(iRow, 8).Value
    date4 = Cells(iRow, 9).Value
    conso4 = Cells(iRow, 10).Value
    date5 = Cells(iRow, 11).Value
    conso5 = Cells(iRow, 12).Value
    date6 = Cells(iRow, 13).Value
    conso6 = Cells(iRow, 14).Value

    Set chartPut = Charts.Add
    With chartPut
        .SetSourceData Source:=Range("STATS!$A$2:$F$2")
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = modem
        'conso values
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "conso1; conso2; conso3; conso4; conso5; conso6"
        'date values
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "date1; date2; date3; date4; date5; date6 "

    End With

Loop



End Sub
```

The thing is, i can't get the "conso" and "date" values to be accepted as data values to the table....
any ideas?

Comment: So, it's a *chart* you're trying to create, not a *table*

Answer (score 0):

To set constant values for the curve use an array.

```
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Array(conso1, conso2, conso3, conso4, conso5, conso6)

.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Array(date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, date6)
```

**EDIT**

So you want your series to refer to those cells dynamically, and the problem you are facing is that you dont know a priori the last row of the range. All you need is to set your range and feed it to the chart's series.

```
Sub addConsoCharts()
    Dim iRow As Long, modem As String, dates As Range, consos As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo Finished
    With Sheets("Sheet1") ' <-- Set to the name of your worksheet
        iRow = 2
        Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(iRow, 1))
            modem = .Cells(iRow, 2).Value
            Set dates = Union(.Cells(iRow, 1), .Cells(iRow, 5), .Cells(iRow, 7), .Cells(iRow, 9), .Cells(iRow, 11), .Cells(iRow, 13))
            Set consos = Union(.Cells(iRow, 4), .Cells(iRow, 6), .Cells(iRow, 8), .Cells(iRow, 10), .Cells(iRow, 12), .Cells(iRow, 14))
            With ThisWorkbook.Charts.Add
                .ChartArea.ClearContents
                .Name = "Conso_" & iRow
                With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                  .Name = modem
                  .XValues = dates
                  .Values = consos
                End With
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = Range("STATS!$A$2:$F$2")

            End With
            iRow = iRow + 1
          Loop
    End With
Finished:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub CleanupConsosCharts() ' <-- to delete all these charts if needed
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim ch As Chart
    For Each ch In ThisWorkbook.Charts
        If ch.Name Like "Conso_*" Then ch.Delete
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

p.s. I have added to you a cleanup routine, you might need it to remove those charts and since they are many it will be tedious to remove them by hand.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want your values to be dynamic and referring to cells? From reading your code it looked like you want to hard-code them from the present values. From seeing `conso1 = Cells(iRow, 4).Value` ...

Comment: Yes firstly i meant the  <<Source:=Range("STATS!$A$2:$F$2")>> should be dynamic, as in the actual code it's hard coded to a certain range. Secondly the values would be ideally dynamic, so that as values are added to the table, the graph would only display the 5 newest values

Comment: How many curves do you nees? I mean each column date_i (date1, date2, etc) will be a different series? or a series for each row where the values are (date1, date2 etc)??

Comment: a series for each row where the values are, the date bening the x values, and the values being the (conso1, conso2...)

Comment: @did12345 Look at the edit. I am not 100% sure but hopefully this is what you are looking for.